# Centos find coredump files

Tags: linux, regex, find

I want to use regex to find all coredump files under a directory. The pattern of the file name is `core.1234`

```
find /public_html -type f -regextype sed -regex "core.{[0-9]+:[0-9]+}"
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 3):

You missed some info on how -regex works

> -regex pattern
>                 File name matches regular expression pattern.  This is a match
>                 on the whole path, not a search.  For example, to match a file
>                 named `./fubar3', you can use the regular expression`.*bar.'
>                 or `.*b.*3', but not`f.*r3'.  The regular expressions
>                 understood by find are by default Emacs Regular Expressions,
>                 but this can be changed with the -regextype option

In particular the regex needs to match the whole path. You don't need to change the regex type or even supply a `-regex`

```
find /public_html  -name "core.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

does the trick and will find core files at any level below /public_html.

Answer (score 0):

/public_html is part of the path, so try `find /public_html -type f -regextype sed -regex ".*/core.{[0-9]+:[0-9]+}"`

Answer (score 0):

```
find /public_html -type f -regextype sed -regex "/public_html/core.[0-9]\+"
```

EDIT: Added example

```
$ ls public_html/
core.asdd  core.1asd  core.123  core.1234  core.12362  core.1456 core.8452

$ find /public_html -type f -regextype sed -regex "/public_html/core.[0-9]\+"
/public_html/core.123
/public_html/core.1234
/public_html/core.1456
/public_html/core.12362
/public_html/core.8452
```

Comment: Can you explain how this solves the problem?

Comment: u can use regexp as is requested in question. This syntac accept one or more numbers after dot in case of part after dot is process number, which can have different number of digits. Also solve problem with directory name in regex formula Example in aswer